# XPath in Java does not return the results intermittently

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to make a custom XML diff checker and I am facing an issue consistently when using DOM in java.
I have 2 DOM Documents to which I have parsed an XML file and the same XML file with modifications. I see that some times when using different files the Xpath is not able to return results to a nodelist thus the nodelist is having a length of 0.

Instead while using the getElementByTagName API I am able to get consistent results

I tried against various files and see that the issue is intermittent. Has anyone else seen this issue ?

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's completely possibe but hard to say without any code to read.